# Making incorrect URL's default to database value

Tags: php, url

Imagine a value in a database - e.g. Raquel_Welch - that represents a page URL (e.g. mysite/People/Raquel_Welch). Now imagine if someone types in the URL incorrectly, like any of the following...

```
mysite/People/Raquel Welch
mysite/People/raquel_welch
mysite/People/raquel welch
```

In other words, the URL is spelled correctly, but the letter case is wrong and/or there's no underscore. Rather than fetch a 404 error page, I'd like the URL to simply default to the proper URL - mysite/People/Raquel_Welch

Does anyone know how to do this?

Incidentally, Wikipedia has a similar feature; if you type in a URL without an underscore, it will default to the proper URL, though it doesn't appear to work for cases... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raquel Welch

Rather than automatically capitalize the first letter of each word, I think I'd prefer to have the URL simply default to a value in my database.

Comment: Perhaps you could try migrating to a MVC and use the URL & compare the similarity between strings stored using `levenshtein`

Comment: Is this what you mean by MVC? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller I'll do some research on it.

Comment: Indeed, Model View Controller. Makes it easier to work with URLs imo

Answer (score 0):

Look up the key from the URL case-and-underscore insensitively (this requires storing a normalized version in the DB, for instance all lowercase and all underscores), and then if the URL doesn't match the canonical version, send back a 301 redirect to the canonical path.

Comment: OK, I looked up 301 redirect. So if my URL doesn't match the value stored in the database, it simply triggers a script to insert 301 redirect code in my page's head section. However, I'm a little confused about matching. For example, if the URL is Raquel_Welch, then neither of these URL's are a match: 1) raquel welch, 2) Jaguar. However, the first example - "raquel welch" - is a de facto match, because it has the right letters (though they're lower case), along with a space representing an underscore. So how do I let my site know that "raquel welch" should be redirected to Raquel_Welch?

Comment: You may have already answered my last question; I'm not sure what you mean by "look up the key."